# ms sql server linux docker asking for file in D:\

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am now trying to restore `.bak` file of MS SQL Server 2008 to docker `mssql-serverlinux` in order to see the content inside and draw my own scheman in `Postgres`

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database) and conclude that my command to restore it to my container supposed to be in single line

`sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE mytrash FROM DISK = '/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"`

Here is the full error and directory I place the `bak` file. Since it will be no use when I finish I name the directory `trash` in order to delete it later.

```
root@891ce27ef07a:/trash# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE mytrash FROM DISK = '/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
Password:
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
File 'dbERP_New_Data' cannot be restored to 'D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA_1.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
File 'dbERP_New_Log' cannot be restored to 'D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA_1.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
root@891ce27ef07a:/trash# pwd
/trash
root@891ce27ef07a:/trash# ls
dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak
root@891ce27ef07a:/trash#
```

My `docker-compose`. For any one who would like to show me the answer.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mssql:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "hardlongpassword"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data
        target: /trash
```

Update
I tried to move the location according to the TZHX comment from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database#restore-your-database-on-linux)
I got new error now

```
1>
1> RESTORE DATABASE NewDB
2> FROM DISK = '/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak'
3> WITH MOVE 'NewDB' TO '/trash/NewDB.mdf',
4> MOVE 'NewDB' TO '/trash/NewDB_Log.ldf'
5> GO
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
Logical file 'NewDB' is not part of database 'NewDB'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Update2:
From [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/109/sql-server-restore-filelistonly/). I am reading the output

```
1> RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK ='/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak' WITH FILE=1
2> GO
LogicalName                                                                                                                      PhysicalName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Type FileGroupName                                                                                                                    Size                 MaxSize              FileId               CreateLSN                   DropLSN                     UniqueId                             ReadOnlyLSN                 ReadWriteLSN                BackupSizeInBytes    SourceBlockSize FileGroupId LogGroupGUID                         DifferentialBaseLSN         DifferentialBaseGUID                 IsReadOnly IsPresent TDEThumbprint                              SnapshotUrl
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbERP_New_Data                                                                                                                   D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA.mdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       D    PRIMARY                                                                                                                                     256311296       35184372080640                    1                           0                           0 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000                           0                           0            143196160             512           1 NULL                                        73150000001788800289 B582C71F-CCDF-4030-9CF8-30785258D515          0         1 NULL                                       NULL
dbERP_New_Log                                                                                                                    D:\MSSQL\Data\dbWINS_MPMBA_1.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     L    NULL                                                                                                                                       2945384448       35184372080640                    2                           0                           0 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000                           0                           0                    0             512           0 NULL                                                           0 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000          0         1 NULL                                       NULL

(2 rows affected)
```

update3:

```
1> RESTORE DATABASE dbERP_New_Data
2> FROM DISK = '/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak'
3> WITH MOVE 'dbERP_New_Data' TO '/trash/dbERP_New_Data.mdf',
4> MOVE 'dbERP_New_Log' TO '/trash/dbERP_New_Log.ldf'
5> GO
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "/trash/dbERP_New_Data.mdf". Operating system error 87: "87(The parameter is incorrect.)".
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 891ce27ef07a, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Update4:
[image: It does add new mdf file]

Comment: You need to tell SQL Server you want to move the files when restoring them. The .bak knows where the files existed when the backup was taken and will default to trying to restore them in the same place.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I had followed your comment. Now it raises new error messages.

Comment: The error message clearly includes the (logical) names of the files you're moving: `dbERP_New_Data` and `dbERP_New_Log`. Use those in the `MOVE`, not `NewDB`.

Comment: Do you mean this? I just update my question. It is update3

Comment: Now it's telling you that it doesn't like the path `/trash/dbERP_New_Log.mdf`. Is `/trash` part of the root FS? SMB/NFS shares are not (yet) supported. You could try a different (writable) path that's part of the container itself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes. It can it does create new file to host directory. Update4 will add my picture. One moment.

Comment: Sounds like it runs into trouble with a file API. Check your `dmesg`. Or it might be something as mundane as running out of disk space -- error handling is probably not as sophisticated as under Windows right now, as it seems to be mapping Unix errors to Windows error codes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert root@891ce27ef07a:/trash# dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167082/discussion-between-jeroen-mostert-and-sarit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, restoring database files to a volume on the host doesn't work (at least not with the default options on a MacOS host; there may be advanced Docker options to get it  to work). What will work is restoring the files within the host itself:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbERP_New_Data
FROM DISK = '/trash/dbWINS_MPMBA201803141100.bak'
WITH MOVE 'dbERP_New_Data' TO '/root/dbERP_New_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'dbERP_New_Log' TO '/root/dbERP_New_Log.ldf'
```

Probably not something you should do for a production setup, but good enough if you only need to access the database for a short while.